# Multiple on Click bindings on single button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add GATracking on a set of pages. Both on pageload and on click of specific buttons. I wanted to generalise the code so that there is not much rework required. Some functions already have binding on it and using multiple bindings on jquery is not a good option. Also, i dont want to add inline function calls.

I can either make an array corresponding to id's and fetch those values on call or i can make the explicit calls on buttons/divs with href and call a separate function when the binding has been done already. 
I was looking for a more generic solution that keeps most of the coding in one class and can be used across. What should i do?

Example :

1) `<div id="submit" class="submitClass">` (in this case, the onClick binding has already been done and multiple binding is not a good practice in jquery).

2)`<li><a href="/" onclick='GATracking(<param1>,<param2>);'>Home</a></li>` (can add like this on different functions but that would be very tedious wont be generic)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure if this may help, but have you tried adding bindings based on class and other more specific query selectors?

Comment: to understand you more you need to use genral function for a tag and div ?

Answer (score 0):

You could add arguments to each time

```
<div id="submit" class="submitClass">
```

jQuery

```
var time = 0;
$("#submit").on("click", function(){
  if(time == 1){
    //Do something here
  } else if(time == 2){
    //Do something here
  } else if(time == 3){
    //Do something here
  } else {
    //default 0
  }
  time+=1;
});
```